# Have boundary (using numcases) facing outward towards right

Tags: equations

I have the following code:

```
\begin{numcases}{text}{\hat{\alpha}_{j}\,=\,}
  2 \pi R\bigl[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\bigr] \\
  0 
\end{numcases}
```

How can I change it so that I have something like this(not code):

```
2 \pi R\bigl[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\bigr]     } text   
0
```

In other words, how can I change the position of the '{' to face this direction '}'

thanks,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also `rcases` from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{rcases}
2 πR\bigl[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\bigr] \\
0
\end{rcases} = x
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does `rcases` allow for numbering of the individual "cases"?

Comment: @Mico I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `empheq`, rather than `cases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace =x}]{align}
&a\\
&b
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems nice, but I can't seem to get hold of the sty file for this (I am using TexnichCenter)

Comment: Where can I download this? I have already tried online but with no luck, I also tried downloading via miktex 2.9 but it froze..

Comment: update: I have the empheq.dtx, how can I get a .sty file?

Comment: @Michael Sorry, but I know nothing of MiKTeX. It should never be necessary to download `.dtx` files for distributed packages. Sometimes the MiKTeX repositories are down, try with another one.

Comment: @Michaël: You have to install the `mathtools` package with `MiKTeX Package Manager`. Don't do it by hand.

Comment: I searched for this too using Texnic center and Mixtek Package managers, no luck. Can't find .sty, I have the .dtx files though, tried using 'tex empheq.dtx' command and seemed to not work properly. Just add this command line to my documemt as text

Comment: If you run LaTeX on  `empheq.dtx`, you'll get the package's user guide. To create `empheq.sty`, you should run LaTeX on `empheq.ins`. But, as others have already pointed out, you shouldn't be going down this route at all. Instead, you really should figure out how to run the MikTeX Package Manager app; it'll let you select the package or packages that should be installed, and the app will take care of the rest. Separately, don't look for solutions in TexnicCenter -- that's the front end, not the TeX distribution itself.

Answer (score 2):

With empheq, you can align your formulae in three ways. With the `overload` option, you can use a simpler syntax: the AMS environments accept an optional argument. A drawback is that they no more can break across pages, but still can have this feature returning to the original version with the `AmSalign`, `AmSgather`, &c., environments. To get the same subnumbering as in `numcases`, you can nest these environments in a `subequations` environment.

Here a demo of the 3 possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}[right={\empheqrbrace =x}]
 2 π R\bigl[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\bigr] \\
 0
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\medskip
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}[right={\empheqrbrace =x}]
 & 2 π R\bigl[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\bigr] \\
 & 0
\end{align}

\end{subequations}
\medskip
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}[right={\empheqrbrace =x}]
 2 π R\bigl[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\bigr] \\
  0
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]g

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[right={\empheqrbrace=\text{text}}]{align}
  &\hat{\alpha}_{j}=2 \pi R\bigl[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\bigr] \\
  &0 
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]